# returning multiple value output python

Tags: python

> Write a function `create_box` that takes three inputs: `height`
> (rows), `width` (columns), and a character `char` and creates a
> `height * width` box using the character `char`.

This is my code:

```
def create_box(height, width, char):
    for i in range (height):
        for j in range(width):
            z = char * j + "\n"
 
    return z
```

The problem with this code is it returns only one line of output. I want to know how is it possible to return the complete box? Can we place the `return` statement in such a way that it returns after completing all the iterations of first for loop?

I also tried this:

```
def create_box(height, width, char):
    z = ""
    for i in range (height): 
        for j in range(width):
            z += char * width + "\n"  
            
        return z

ma = create_box(3, 5, "!")
print(ma)
```

The output is:

```
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
!!!!!
```

Comment: You'll want to initialise `z` to an empty string an *append* new lines to it in the loop…

Comment: @deceze... i  tried this solution but it does not work as it prints so many extra rows.

Comment: Show that attempt and the "extra rows" please…?

Comment: @deceze...I edited with my output.

Comment: You don't need the second loop... Just `for _ in range(height): z += char * width + "\n"`

Comment: Seems like it works, what is our expected output?

Comment: @kada..This can work. But I need to solve it  with nested loops. It's an assignment to understand nested loops but I got stuck here.

Comment: @Tokerikoo...Need to solve with nested for loops

Comment: Has your question been resolved?

Comment: @codeman.. no it has not been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost done it correctly with your second approach: This is the working code.

```
def create_box(height, width, char):
    z = ""
    for i in range (height): 
        for j in range(width):
            z += char   # Width number of chars
        z += '\n'       # Next row
            
    return z

ma = create_box(3, 5, "!")
print(ma)
```

All you did was mess up the indentation of your return statement, and add to the string wrongly. If you don't get the logic here, post a comment and I'll explain it fully.

**Outputs:**

```
>>> print(create_box(1, 1, '-'))
-

>>> print(create_box(3, 2, '* '))
* * 
* * 
* * 

# Etc etc
```

In response to your comment:

The reason your first code didn't work was that the approach was wrong, take a look at this:

```
z = 0
for i in range(5):
    z += i
print(z)

# You expected this to output 5, it doesn't
```

The second attempt was wrong on two counts:

1. Your `return` statement was wrongly indented, making it so that the function stopped executing after it completed the first iteration of the outer loop. See below:

```
def hello():
    print("This gets printed")
    return
    print("This is never executed")

hello()
# Run it and see for yourself!
```

2. The `z` variable: You had z randomly going up, all the second for loop needed to do was add one `char` to `z` every iteration.

Anything else you need clarification on?

Comment: @Codeman...Thanks a lot. Can you help me understand my first code attempt in question?

Comment: @Codeman...Why my first for loop execute only once in that code? After the assignment of z, shouldn't it run again for i ?